# Rotate alpha numeric and numbers places

Tags: c#

I need to rotate the places on numeric and alpha-numeric places.

Need to see first the alpha-numeric and then the numeric characters.

For example:

```
11AA
20BA
70D
9SD
```

I need to get this:

```
AA11
BA20
D70
SD9
```

I tried with reverse - but its not what I need

```
public static string Reverse( string s )
{
    char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse( charArray );
    return new string( charArray );
}
```

Comment: We'll need to get more info about the input pattern. Are the inputs always the same size (in your sample they aren't)? Can letters and numbers be mixed (A12B) or they are always consecutive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Char.IsDigit`:

```
public static string Reverse (string s)
{
    char[] digits = s.Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray();
    char[] letters = s.Where(c => !Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray();

    return new string(letters) + new string(digits);
}
```

Although the approach I suggest isn't the best, as in it creates two new char arrays and as multiple steps. There is probably a way to do it without having to create the 2 intermediate char arrays.

Comment: You can omit the `char[] chars = s.ToCharArray();` and simply use linq operations on string `char[] digits = s.Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray();`

Comment: @m.rogalski I always forget if you can or not on a string

Answer (score 1):

*Linq* solution (letters and digits concatenation):

```
  public static string Reverse(string s) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) // public method wants validation
      return s; // or throw exception

    return string.Concat(s
      .Where(char.IsLetter)
      .Concat(s.Where(char.IsDigit)));
  }
```